# DataSourceResult does not make paging, filtering and sorting in kendo-grid

Tags: c#, angular, datatable, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I've read this [tutorial](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/listview/binding/ajax-binding) and it says that

> Use the `ToDataSourceResult` extension method to convert your `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` to a `Kendo.UI.DataSourceResult` object. This  extension method will page, filter, sort, or group your data using the information provided by the DataSourceRequest object.

So my code looks like this:

```
var parkDataTable = new DataTable("tmp");
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlDataReader dr = null;
using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
try {
    cmd = new SqlCommand("FooStoredProcedure", db.Database.Connection as SqlConnection,
    transaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;        
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    parkDataTable.Load(dr);
    return parkDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Table).FirstOrDefault()
        .ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
finally{
    dr?.Close();
    cmd?.Dispose();
}
```

So I've converted to `IEnumerable`, but filtering, paging or sorting cannot be done at `kendo-grid` of `Angular 2` application.

Could you clarify what am I doing wrong?

My `kendo-grid` table does not have paging, sorting, filtering:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Grid needs to be sortable, pageable, filterable, etc. in order the respective UI to be present:

[Filtering](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/)

[Paging](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/paging/)

[Sorting](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/sorting/)

Furthermore, the request parameters need to be processed in a way that will make them understandable by the DataSourceRequest modelbinder:

[ToDataSourceRequestString](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/toDataSourceRequestString/)

You can check out the following integration guide for further details and a sample project:

[Kendo UI for Angular Grid - MVC/Core integration](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/mvc-integration/)